# Access WebViewPage from custom HTML Helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper, viewpage

I've got a ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor Web Application.

I've got a `WebViewPage` extension:

```
public static bool Blah(this WebViewPage webViewPage)
{
   return blah && blah;
}
```

And i want to access this from my `HtmlHelper` extension:

```
public static MvcHtmlString BlahHelper(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName)
{
   // how can i get access to the WebViewPage extension method here?
}
```

I can of course duplicate the functionality of the `WebViewPage` extension if i had to, but just wondering if it's possible to access it from the HTML helper.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
// Warning: this cast will crash
// if you are not using the Razor view engine
var wvp = (WebViewPage)htmlHelper.ViewDataContainer;
var result = wvp.Blah();
```

Comment: Darin to the rescue AGAIN. Thanks buddy. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should change that method to extend `HttpContextBase`, which you can access from both `HtmlHelper` and `WebViewPage`.

Comment: the question wasn't really about the functionality of the extension, but how to achieve what i'm asking in a general sense. I've edited the question to reflect that

Comment: I don't think that's possible; explore `htmlHelper` in the Locals window and see if you can find it.

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
((WebViewPage)htmlHelper.ViewContext.View). Blah()
```

Comment: Nice try. It appears that `View` is actually the view engine, not the view page. And i'm using a custom view engine (Razor CSHTML generator), so the type is `PrecompiledRazorViewEngine`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the accepted answer led me to the solution (+1). Maybe this hint helps somebody else too.
Additionally I had to use the generic version of WebViewPage inside a strongly type view.
Otherwise I got a type cast exception.

```
public static MvcHtmlString ToBodyEnd<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, ...) {
       var vp = (DerivedWebViewPage<TModel>)htmlHelper.ViewDataContainer;
    //... more code ...
    }
```